# Android AsyncTask and NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I am working on an Android app that uses Jsoup.  Early on in development, I "worked around" having to implement any kind of threading because I just wanted to get the bulk of the code completed before tackling threading.  I am now attempting to use AsyncTask, but I am still getting the NetworkOnMainThreadException error.  I have read plenty of tutorials and SO posts on AsyncTask, but still can seem to identify the problem.  When I add the StrictMode... code, the app works as desired except for the UI lockup when loading the data using Jsoup.  If anyone could show me what I am doing wrong pertaining to AsyncTask, I would appreciate it. (P.S. I know there is plenty of code redundancy to be cleaned up, but I want to get AsyncTask working first)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

            /***This is the work around used***/
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            /******/  



            up = new TreeMap<Double, String[]>(); 

            c1 = "example.com/1";
            //instansiate textviews (6)
                    doc1 = doc;
            c2 = "example.com/2";
            //instansiate textviews (6)
                    doc2 = doc;
            c3 = "example.com/3";
            //instansiate textviews (6)
            doc3 = doc;

            // instansiate textviews(16)

            new Download().execute(c1,c2,c3);

   } 
        private class Download extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[][]> {
            @Override
            protected String[][] doInBackground(String... urls){
                out = new String[7][3];
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).data().get();          
                    //days, times, and cs arrays created and filled

                    String[] out1arr = {days[0], times[0], cs[0]};
                    //...all 7
                    String[] out7arr = {days[6], times[6], cs[6]};
                    String[][] outarrs = {out1arr,out2arr,out3arr,out4arr,out5arr,out6arr,out7arr};
                    for (int i= 0; i < out.length; i++){
                        out[i] = outarrs[i];
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                return (out);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String[][] result){

                Do(/*textviews(6)*/, c1, a, outa, "example1"); //a is previously instantiated double array, outa is preiously instantiated string array
                Do(/*textviews(6)*/, c2, b, outb, "example2");
                Do(/*textviews(6)*/, c3, c, outc, "example3");


                upc00.setText(getUpc()[0][0]);
                //setText for all 16
                upc32.setText(getUpc()[3][2]);

            }

            private void Do(TextView t, TextView u, TextView v, TextView w, TextView x, TextView y,String webpage, double[] darr, String[] sarr, String show){


                t.setText(doInBackground(webpage)[0][0]);
                //...all 6
                y.setText(doInBackground(webpage)[1][2]);       
                for (int i =0; i < darr.length; i++){
                    darr[i] = tis[i];
                    up.put(darr[i], out[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        private ArrayList<String[]> getMap(){
                //...
            return s;
        }
        private String[][] getUpc(){
            //...
            return upc;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework calls `doInBackground` you should not call it yourself. Your code makes a call from `onPostExecute` which is called by the framework on the UI thread. So effectively your calls run on the UI thread.

Move your fetching logic all into the `doInBackgound` method. The `onPostExecute` method should be used to deliver the results to the caller.

Comment: Thanks.  I will need to rearrange a lot of code, but based on the changes you've suggested, load times are now ~1 sec rather than 10-15 as before.